# Sql Server 2005 Connectivity with netbean IDE

Tags: jsp

I have made every setting required for it changed the vip setting and tcp/ip setting in sql server configuration manager. Made the dynamic port to 1433.

Still i get this error. I am not able to connect to sql server while an instance is always running when i am making connection.

this is the error i got every time.

**Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:sqlserver://DANISH-PC\SQLEXPRESS:1433;databaseName=Student_Data using com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver (The TCP/IP connection to the host DANISH-PC, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused: connect. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".)**

through this code i want to insert data

```
<sql:setDataSource var="Stddata" driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" 
url="jdbc:sqlserver://DANISH-PC\SQLEXPRESS:1433;databaseName=StudentData" 
user="danish-PC/danish"
password=""/>

    <sql:update dataSource="${Stddata}" scope="page" >
       INSERT INTO Student (Name,FatherName,Class_No,Address,Phone) 
       Values(<sql:param value="${param.value}}"></sql:param>,
       <sql:param value="${param.value}}"></sql:param>,
       <sql:param value="${param.value}}"></sql:param>,
       <sql:param value="${param.value}}"></sql:param>,
       <sql:param value="${param.value}}"></sql:param>
       )
    </sql:update>
```

Comment: Are you able to connect to this db server from a standard sql client (apart from your code)?

Comment: yeah i am able to connect to db server.